# Error while passing parameters in a python3 function

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am writing a Linked List Program in python 3.7.7
For that, I've created 2 classes named: `Node` and `Linked List`.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
```

The node class contains the structure of each and every nodes i.e it has 2 attributes.
The Linked List class contains the following functions:

```
class LinkedList:
# UTILITY FUNCTIONS
# Function to push a node
def lpush(head_ref, new_data):

    # allocate node
    new_node = Node(new_data)

    new_node.next = head_ref
    head_ref = new_node

    return head_ref

# Function to print linked list
def lprint(node):
    count = 0
    while node != None:
        print(node.data, end=" ")
        node = node.next
        count = count + 1
```

In the driver function, I am creating a node(head) object of class Node with a value -1.

```
head = Node(-1)
```

and I've created an object of the class LinkedList, by the name Llist

```
llist = LinkedList()
```

Now I am trying to insert the values in the linked list by calling the lpush() function

```
for i in range(20, 0, -1):
head = llist.lpush(head, i)
```

but it is throwing the following error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/subham-brc/Python-3.7.3/Python Files/Linked List/8.py", line 79, in <module>
    head = llist.lpush(head, i)
TypeError: lpush() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Just add self in the signature of your functions `def lpush(self, head_ref, new_data)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `self` as first parameter to `lpush` and `lprint` - even if you don’t use it. These are implictly provided whenever you call a method on a `LinkedList` object.

Comment: I have passed 'self' as the first parameter: llist.lpush(self.head, I) but now I am getting the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/subham-brc/Python-3.7.3/Python Files/Linked List/8.py", line 79, in <module>
    head = llist.lpush(self.head, i)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: No, you don’t have to (mustn’t) explicitly provide the self parameter, Python does that for you. You just call the method e.g. `llist.lpush(i)`